# Read package metadat (XML) from SSIDB

Tags: .net, sql-server, xml, ssis, sql-server-2012

How can I get metadata of a package from SSISDB. Online search ended up on [this answer](https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/100651/querying-ssisdb-text-search-in-the-packet-definiti.html) which claims to be getting that but requires to modify system SP which I afraid to do.

It used be as easy as querying table in earlier versions

```
SELECT name, CONVERT(xml,CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),packagedata))
FROM msdb.dbo.sysssispackages
```

If not XML then at least if I can get the physical path of each package (i.e. something like `D/SomeFolder/Package.dtsx`) then I will extract the same.

Any help would be appreciated.

**P.S.** I am open for `.NET` solution too. I just want to get metadata of packages stored in SSISDB.

Comment: Perhaps you can use this solution http://www.techbrothersit.com/2013/07/ssis-read-ssis-package-filedtsx-for.htmlI 
Know it takes a little work before you can perform searches in XML metadata